# How to control two loading method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, metronic

I have two different type of "loading" methods as shown below; one of them is used to display loading spinner in the middle of the page whenever AJAX call request begins. The other method is used to display loading spinner on the given div i.e. datatable. On the other hand, when calling showLoading() method on retrieving data, it causes the other spinner to be displayed, but I want to display the spinner only on the middle of given div by showLoading() method. Of course I think of that to use a single method and check the div parameter for displaying spinner, but I cannot use showLoading() method during page loading (partialview is loading) as the datatable is not rendered when page loading. So, how can I use just a single method for these two situations? Is it possible or not?

```
//Displays "loading" spinner whenever an AJAX request begins
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    App.blockUI({
        target: '#div-page-content',
        animate: true
    });
});

//Displays "loading" spinner on the given container
function showLoading(container) {             
    if (container == null) {
        container = '#div-page-content';
    }
    App.blockUI({
        target: container,
        animate: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Just finished watching The Good, The Bad and the Ugly and see this. What are the odds...

Comment: @AliGajani I strongly suggest **For a Few Dollars More** and the other series :))

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Is there something that does not work? Secondly, I have no idea what partialview is.

Comment: @trincot Everything is working properly. But when datatable is rendered with records, the main loading spinner is displayed in the middle of the page and the other spinner is displayed in the middle of the datatable at the same time. If I use only the second method (showLoading()) it displays the spinner on the datatable, **but** in that case when partialview is loading, I cannot display loading spinner by using showLoading() method as there is no div rendered yet :(

Comment: Any idea regarding to this issue?

Comment: @ClintEastwood: I have watched all 3 in sequence ;)

Comment: @AliGajani Good :) What about the solution of this problem?